# Deploying RoR project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Some background. I created an account on AWS to try out the AWS Elastic Beanstalk solution for deploying RoR apps. I then followed the guide on Amazons site ([Getting Started with Eb](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html))which works fine.

I am however puzzled by this, When I create an application using the eb cli tool and specify the AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key from my account it does not show up in my AWS Management Console.

Do I need to perform some special task to create a connection between the app created from CLI tool to my AWS Management Console?

I cant find anyone else having this problem, dont know if I have missed something obvious here. I followed the [guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html) when I created the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely overlooked the fact that you can choose region in the top menu. Default region was N. Virginia and I was deploying to Europe (Ireland).

Keeping question and answer if anyone else googles for this issue.